# Why does Outlook 2013 get confused when my network changes?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013, office365

I use Outlook 2013 on my laptop, connected to Office365 Exchange.  At the office I have a generic docking station which gives me dual screen, USB, Ethernet etc.  Outlook works great most of the time:

When I arrive at work and connect the docking station my wireless disconnects and the Ethernet connects.  Most of the time Outlook is already open and the status remains "Connected to: MS Exchange" and "All folders up to date".  So a few hours later I notice that I don't have any new mails so I close Outlook and reopen it.  Suddenly a whole pile of emails download - they've been sitting on the Exchange server, but Outlook hasn't fetched them!  The same thing happens when going from Ethernet to Wifi.  When I switch networks, I get no errors, everything looks fine, but emails don't download until I restart Outlook.  Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

TL;DR:
When switching between wifi & ethernet with Outlook open, Outlook stops synchronizing with Exchange and shows no error messages.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Other Related posts: [Outlook 2010 prompts for password when switching from LAN to wireless](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0c47baf5-5052-4a1f-920e-57c9b59f2823/outlook-2010-prompts-for-password-when-switch-from-lan-to-wireless?forum=outlook), [Outlook won't reconnect after switching networks](http://superuser.com/questions/988809/outlook-wont-reconnect-after-switching-networks), [Outlook disconnects on Undock](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/403675-outlook-2010-disconnecting-when-laptop-is-undocked)